# wrong number of arguments (4 for 1..3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i'm struggling to understand why this is happen with destroy method since everything on controller and routes is ok!

if someone passed through this way please could give me a hint?

**Routes**

```
 resources :users, :as => "" do
    resources  :sections, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy, :index] 
  end
```

**Controller**

```
def destroy
    @section = Section.find(params[:id])
    @section.destroy
    redirect_to sections_url
    flash[:notice] = "Section deleted" 
  end
```

**View**

```
<%= render :partial => "section", :collection => @sections %>
```

**Partial**

```
<%= link_to  section.name, section_path(current_user, section) %> 
<%= button_to 'Remove', current_user, section, :data => { :confirm => 'Confirm?' }, :class=> "buttom",  method: :delete %>
```

Comment: can you please present the complete error message?

Comment: Your `button_to` helper arguments are wrong..

Comment: i forget to add the path on destroy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**codeit**, **Stefan** did what you guys said but did not work, so i tried the path instead and worked!

```
<%= button_to 'Remove', section_path(current_user, section), :data => { :confirm => 'Confirm?' }, :class=> "button",  method: :delete %>
```

Comment: You're right, the path from `[current_user, section]` would be `user_section_path`.

Comment: yes, but i'm using resources <pre>:users, :as => "" do</pre> on routes, so just section_path work.

Answer (score 2):

That error means that some function takes 1 to 3 arguments, but you gave to it 4 arguments.

Please see the row number in the error and look up the function, then open documentation and look up how to use that function. Often functions works differently as instance methods and class methods.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be this method call:

```
button_to 'Remove', current_user, section, :data => { :confirm => 'Confirm?' }, :class=> "buttom",  method: :delete
```

The pair `current_user` and `section` has to been passed as an array:

```
button_to 'Remove', [current_user, section], confirm: 'Confirm?', class: "buttom",  method: :delete
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `button_to` helper arguments are wrong.

Try this:

```
  <%= button_to 'Remove', {:action => :destroy, :user => current_user, :id => section}, {:data => { :confirm => 'Confirm?' }, :class=> "buttom",  method: :delete} %>
```